# app:popupTheme not applying to both overflow menus

Tags: android, material-design

The popup overflow menu on the toolbar works fine however when I pressed the menu button on my phone, it's overflow menu (the one at the bottom of the screen) still inherits the toolbar theme which I've set to the dark theme to get the white text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />
```

The theme of my app is set to the AppTheme which inherits `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. It's the default values for now.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I'm still new to Android so I'm not sure if I'm overlooking a simple mistake or if it's a simple fix.